# Unable to enter while loop:"Segmentation fault"

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, coredump

I don't know why I am getting segmentation fault when trying to do while(mapArray[currX][currY]!='t')
Every things is working fine as far as I can run.

```
#include<iostream
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

struct array{
private:
char mapArray[10][10];
char tempChar;
queue<int> xComponent;
queue<int> yComponent;
vector<vector<char>> visited;
vector<char> answer;
int xtarget=1+rand() % 10;
int ytarget=1+rand() % 10;

void inputMap();
void moveRight(int xC,int yC);
void moveDown(int xC,int yC);
void moveLeft(int xC,int yC);
void moveUp(int xC,int yC);
void move();
bool isOk(int xC,int yC);
void showPath();
public:
void run();
};

void array::moveRight(int xC,int yC){
xComponent.push(xC);
yComponent.push(yC);
}

void array::moveDown(int xC,int yC){
xComponent.push(xC);
yComponent.push(yC);
}

void array::moveLeft(int xC,int yC){
xComponent.push(xC);
yComponent.push(yC);
}

void array::moveUp(int xC,int yC){
xComponent.push(xC);
yComponent.push(yC);
}

bool array::isOk(int xC,int yC){
return ((visited[xC][yC]!='v') && (mapArray[xC][yC]!='t'));
if(visited[xC][yC]=='v')
return false;
else
if(mapArray[xC][xC]=='x')
return false;
else
return true;
}

void array::inputMap(){
    cout<<"Values of map"<<endl;
    //Using random numbers
    /*
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            cout<<"Input value for i:"<<i<<" j:"<<j<<endl;
            cin>>mapArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    */
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            int t=rand() % 9;
            char chA='0' + t;
            //cout<<"T:"<<t<<endl;
            //cout<<"CHA:"<<chA<<endl;
            mapArray[i][j]=chA;
            if(i==xtarget&&j==ytarget){
                mapArray[i][j]='t';
            }
            cout<<"i:"<<i<<" j:"<<j<<" "<<mapArray[i][j]<<endl;;
        }
    }
}

void array::move(){
int currX=0,currY=0;
xComponent.push(0);
yComponent.push(0);
cout<<"Debugging move point 1"<<endl;

cout<<"Debugging move point 2"<<endl;
while(mapArray[currX][currY]!='t'){
cout<<"Debugging while:"<<currX+1<<" ";
if((isOk(currX+1,currY) && (currX+1!=10) && (visited[currX+1][currY]!='v')))
moveRight(currX+1,currY);

if((isOk(currX,currY+1) && (currY+1!=10) && (visited[currX+1][currY]!='v')))
moveDown(currX,currY+1);

if((isOk(currX-1,currY) && (currX-1!=-1) && (visited[currX-1][currY]!='v')))
moveLeft(currX-1,currY);

if((isOk(currX,currY-1) && (currY-1!=-1) && (visited[currX][currY-1]!='v')))
moveUp(currX,currY-1);

if( (!xComponent.empty()) && (!yComponent.empty()) ){
    currX=xComponent.front();
    currY=yComponent.front();
    xComponent.pop();
    yComponent.pop();
    visited[currX][currY]='v';
    tempChar=mapArray[currX][currY];
    answer.push_back(tempChar);
}

}

cout<<"Debugging move point 3"<<endl;

/*
xComponent.push(currX);
yComponent.push(currY);
visited[currX][currY]='v';
tempChar=mapArray[currX][currY];
answer.push_back(tempChar);
*/
}

void array::run(){
    cout<<"Inside run()"<<endl;
    cout<<"Target Block x:"<<xtarget<<" y:"<<ytarget<<endl;
    inputMap();
    cout<<"inputMap() done"<<endl;
    move();
    cout<<"move() done"<<endl;
    showPath();
    cout<<"showPath() done"<<endl;
}

void array::showPath(){
    cout<<"Answer:";
    for(int i=0;i<answer.size();i++){
        cout<<answer[i]<<" ";
    }
}

int main(){
cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
array A;
A.run();
return 0;
}
```

I was trying to do bfs on array but I am getting segmentation fault each time I try to access 0,0 element of mapArray

I read on internet and find that when we try to access location which is out of scope we get segmentation fault but in our case it's not.

Comment: Two things to check:  1) All array and vector indices are in bounds.  2) You are not calling `pop` on an empty queue.  *I read on internet and find that when we try to access location which is out of scope we get segmentation fault but in our case it's not* -- I bet that you are getting boundary errors.

Comment: Also, do **not** call your class `array`.  There is a `std::array` class already existing in the C++ library, and your definition may clash with it.

Comment: This is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

One error is that in various places, you are attempting to access the `visited` vector, but no entries have been added to it.

For example:

```
bool array::isOk(int xC, int yC) {
    return ((visited[xC][yC] != 'v') && (mapArray[xC][yC] != 't'));  // <-- out-of-bounds access
//…
```

This will lead to an out-of-bounds access, since `visited` has no entries, and you're attempting to access elements within it.

To confirm this, change that line of code above to:

```
bool array::isOk(int xC, int yC) {
     return ((visited.at(xC).at(yC) != 'v') && (mapArray[xC][yC] != 't'));
```

You should get an `std::out_of_range` exception instead of a segmentation fault.

Comment: I renamed array class to arr and changed 2d vector of type char to 2d array for simplicity to test the logic.
But now I am getting infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all don't name a class a name that is used by the standard library. Naming a class "array" plus declaring away the `std` namespace makes your class collide with `std::array`. (This is why `using namespace std` is a bad idea)
2. The member variable `vector<vector<char>> visited;` is empty but is used all over the place. You need to initialize it to, it looks likes, a 10 by 10 vector of vectors.
3. Beyond that, all the lines like `if((isOk(currX-1,currY) && (currX-1!=-1) && (visited[currX-1][currY]!='v')))` need to guard against out of bounds array accesses before the access happens i.e. `isOkay(...)` accesses `visited`; the way that is written if currX is zero isVisited will be called on -1.